Forex-Python shows me failed connection to HTTPS
I already downloaded forex-python, I verified it was installed in the environment, and I have seen the different extensions and documentation.
When I try to do a simple query like:
c = CurrencyRates()

usd_to_eur = c.get_rate('USD', 'EUR')
print(usd_to_eur)

Till the definition of c is perfect, but then gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
--> 700     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    702 except ClosedPoolError as e:
    703     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='theforexapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR&rtype=fpy (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000221E8DF7D00>: Failed to resolve 'theforexapi.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))

Could someone help me?
I only want to see the historical currencies, is it necessary that I register in theforexapi.com? I thought with the install of the library was enough. Help

Have you checked if the target url https://forexapi.com is still valid ?
